# Visual studio C# project code source file getting huge and slow

Tags: visual-studio

I am working on a visual studio 2010 c# project in which some code source files have 65000 lines.
And its becoming very slow to work on those code source. After writing every 2 letters the file litteraly freeze.
Is there a way gain perfomance in working on those files ?

Comment: Did you have any VS External Tool install on this computer. Something like Reshaper can sometime be very disastrous on performance.

Comment: Hello, the only extensions tha i have installed is ComponentOne and DevExpress.

Comment: I could be due to your computer performance, network connection, VPN, Memory available. Look at the Task Manager to find any clue.